# Multipe errors handling with Observer in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, observer-pattern, es6-class, observers

I am trying to collect all errors thrown by different ajax calls in different places in my app, and after to display **one popup** containing all errors.
I wrote a class where I have an array, which I use to save all coming errors, and once I am done I read from this array and write to the popup.
Here my class where the errors will be collected:

```
class Handler {

    constructor() {
        this.requests = [];
    }

    onSubscribe (call) {
        this.requests.push(call);
    }

    onComplete () {
        if (this.requests.length > 0) {
            // Loop through the array display a dialog with all errors
        }
        this.onUnsubscribe();
    }

    onUnsubscribe () {
        this.requests = [];
    }
}
```

So as we see, the function **onSubscribe** is used to collect the error from the place where it's being thrown, and **onComplete** is used to display the error dialog once all the errors were collected.

From an other hand, I have some ajax calls which are called in different classes (below an example of one call), and there I have to add the error to the errors collection.

```
$.get(url, (response) => {
            // Here when the ajax call is successful
            // No error here, this call should be marked as done
            this.handler.onComplete();
            });
        }).fail((response) => {
            // Here when the ajax call fails
            // The error thrown here should be collected and the call should be marked as done
            this.handler.onSubscribe(response.error);
            this.handler.onComplete();
        });
```

This is what I did, but I am facing 2 problems here:
The first problem if that is the right way to use the Observer Pattern, and the second problem how to know that all calls are done (I thought here about to implement a counter).
I searched everywhere in the forum and in the internet but I couldn't find anything similar...
I am using es6.

Comment: "*and after to display*" - after what exactly? "*how to know that all calls are done*" - all of **which** calls?

Comment: @Bergi to display a dialog with all errors after I collected them. the ajax calls (there one of them)

Comment: "*after I collected them*" - and when do you want to stop collecting? If there is only one call, your code works. If there are multiple calls (which you haven't shown), there needs to be some code which you tell what calls you are making.

Comment: I have multiple calls, in different classes, my problem is how the moment when I have to display the errors dialog

Comment: If these calls in different classes are not related to each other *somehow*, it would mean that you want to wait until all calls **ever** made in your application are completed. If you don't know at what moment you want to display the errors, we cannot help you write code for determining any moment.

Comment: As I said above, I don't know at which moment all the calls are done as they are asynchronous and are in different classes. My problem is that I can't find a way to know when all the calls are done...

Comment: If you cannot define which calls "*all the calls*" means, then by definition there is no way to know when they are done. It doesn't matter that you don't know how to write code to determine that, you first need to tell *us* what you mean.